# Laravel Email verification without Registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working with user mail verification in laravel. What laravel provides is we can verify an email when a user attempt to register.

But I want to verify an email that a user will provide after registering/login with a form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just overriding the users existing email address or are you adding the new email address to a different table?

Comment: adding new email to a different table

Comment: I think you want verify email again after user change email. If that, you just simple make ``email_verified_at`` to null after user change email address.

Comment: Can you show the relationship between the user and the new table? Is there a model for the new table? Also, are you wanting the user to be restricted from the site until they've verified the new email address?

Comment: there is no relation between user and newtable. and user has no rustication to access the system. this is only for validate  the given email.@RossWilson

Comment: Plz ,explain what you need exactly?

Comment: i need to validate some email that are not use for registration purpose .i just need to check is the email is valid or not by verify it all  @mohamedhassan

Comment: You want validate the email field and check if no users sign with this email before,okay?

Comment: naot the email fild i want to validate the email by sending a conformation email to the mail. it can be any email